# Can obligations be substances/objects?

Tags: metaethics, properties, essence, objects, korsgaard

**Background idea:** [H. A. Prichard's following thesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/prichard/#GooRig):

> Prichard’s second argument is equally idiosyncratic. We can have an obligation to do an action long before the action is done. If so, the obligation cannot be a feature of the action, since it exists before the action does. It must be a feature of something else, if it is a feature of anything, and the obvious candidate is the agent.

On the flip-side, then, is it possible for there to be an obligation of which *agents* are then predicated? One will object that an agent is not a property, but has properties; we can speak of composing objects as *parts*, but not as properties, of further objects. However, if the object/property distinction is murkier (due to type-theoretic leveling, say), might it be possible to construe agents as properties in some contexts, and then namely in *this* context?

**Comparison and contrast with a similar distinction:** consider a (hypothetical) difference between [essential and accidental](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental/) obligations. *How* different is this from the preceding, though? The idea *here* seems to be that obligation is still taken for a property of agents, and the distinction turns on *which subcategories* of these kinds of properties we are thinking over. To speak of an essential obligation *seems* to involve such thinking. But if substances and essences are ultimately equivalent somehow, then would we not be able to go back further, to the idea that *an obligation is itself part of the very essence of our being*, so that other parts of our essence attach to this deontic core, and then we are back to looking at agency as a property of some obligation-theoretic essence?<sup>ℰ</sup>

---

<sup>ℰ</sup>Put another, somewhat different way: if an essence is a quiddity (a what-a-thing-is), then is neither an agent a property (somehow) of an obligation, nor an obligation a property of an agent, but are *agents themselves obligations?* Korsgaard seems to indicate something like this in her response to Mackie's opposition to "objectively prescriptive entities," and it appears as the saying (I don't recall where from), "We *are* the categorical imperative." One might reason so:

1. Agents are objects (*A* = *B*).
2. Agents are obligations (*A* = *C*).
3. Therefore, obligations are objects (*B* = *C*).

---

**P.S.** I did find [one article](https://cs.brown.edu/%7Esk/Publications/Papers/Published/dfk-obl-int-prog/paper.pdf) discussing "obligations as objects" but so far I'm not sure how metaphorically or indirectly this is meant (it's a computer science paper).

Comment: "Agents are obligations" premise seems a lot less plausible to me than "obligations are objects" conclusion. A more plausible path to it might be "obligations are concepts, and concepts are abstract objects" (Frege style), see e.g. [Fredericks, Moral responsibility for concepts](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ejop.12547). Of course, it is more common to think of them as properties, but then [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/#AbouExprObje) suggests that object/property distinction is not very significant, and properties can be (non-Fregean) objects.

Comment: Instead of obligations being as quiddity, in deontic logic it's well known that obligations are modalities of actions, in the same way rights or permissibles could be another mode of some other or even the same actions conceivably of the same said agent. Of course there's nothing intrinsically wrong to refer obligations to properties of agents but you'd better justify its significant advantage in your case...

Comment: It is hard to tell without context, but Korsgaard's quote gives off metaphoric vibes. Obligation is traditionally a binary relation, "A is obligated to X". He seems to suggest subsuming the second input under the first and making obligations not quite objects, but unary, properties of the agent. This makes Kantian sense, categorical imperative is there in virtue of the agent's rationality, and general maxims are her "essential properties". In specific circumstances with some actions available, this essence induces the traditional binary obligations. Metaphorically, we "are" the maxims.

Comment: Btw, assuming you insist obligation as quiddities of an agent and if it's true that esse preceeds quiddity, then agents "are not" essentially the maxims of obligations but have to be obliged to be caused by their existence qua existence itself in the similar way as a tree is caused by its seed, that is to say, CI maxims themselves don't really exist either as objects or properties of whatever order in the sense of our common logic but modalities of the esse...

Answer (score 2):

Pritchard is wrong to consider the agent to be the obvious candidate upon which to hang the tag of an obligation. An obligation is a form of belief, and it can be held by the obliger as much as the obliged. If I consider that  everyone is obliged always to respect speed limits, say, that is my personal belief. Others might take the view that it is perfectly rational to disregard speed limits under certain circumstances. In that case, the obligation in question is the abstract subject of my opinion- it is not necessarily a property of the people to whom I believe the obligation applies.

From the perspective I have just outlined, an obligation generally is a form of belief, and beliefs would not normally be considered objects or substances.

Comment: +1 For great instincts about the immateriality of beliefs, however, in a world infested with Platonic thinking, many indeed give weight to the idea that beliefs as propositions inhabit some semi-mental, semi-physical world called the abstract object.  It's surprising how many people believe that a mathematical proposition has some sort of objective reality in the same way a calculator does.

Answer (score 2):

If one takes obligations to be deontic propositions, then it is trivial to argue that such propositions seem to inhabit a metaphysical category of abstract object. The argument:

> Propositions are abstract objects
> Deontic propositions are a hyponym of propositions
> Therefore deontic propositions (an alias of obligations) are abstract objects.

This is quite a sensible and normal interpretation of seeing agents as possessing propositional beliefs and then acting on them in the distant future.

You ask:

> are agents themselves obligations?

I think common sense says in some contexts yes, if it is understood that agents are object complements in the deontic proposition itself. For instance, if the obligation is to carry a child to term in the case of pregnancy (the pro-life ethical stance), then the child becomes an obligation. That is not to say that the agent *becomes* a proposition, but that through elision in a natural language construction the agent *becomes an object* of the proposition. It would be mere economy to elide over the distinction in language, and would not confer some special metaphysical process or status on the drawing of such a conclusion. Such an elision 'there are agents that are (objects of) obligations' might be understood in natural language by the use of nomial adjective 'there are agent obligations'.

Your reasoning:

> Agents are objects (A = B).
> Agents are [objects of] obligations (A = C).
> Therefore, obligations are [types of] objects (B = C).

is obviously specious.

> Bananas are fruits.
> Bananas are [objects of] drawings.
> Therefore, drawings are [types of] fruits.

To which we can respond ['Ceci n'est pas une pipe'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) as understanding bananas-as-drawings and bananas-as-fruits occupy different sorts of categories (types if you prefer!); and then trying to establish hypernymy between them is a category mistake since bananas-as-drawings are abstractions where as bananas-as-fruits are physical things.

Comment: If an obligation, as a deontic proposition, is an abstract object, then we would not want to say that agents are obligations on pain of claiming that agents are abstract (maybe partly abstract, though, even so?), would we? However, can we escape from the land of *abstracta*, here, to an ontology of physical natures? Then I would wonder about saying that an obligation is some individual nature, not just *in* but *as* that nature.

Comment: What I see at play here is mind-body dualism. I think in our intuitional ontological categorization, we admit that obligations are conceived by agents, and that agents can be the object of those obligations, but strictly speaking agents remain in the realm of physical or real things, whereas obligations occupy some middle ground having properties of physical things (like the chemical forces at play in my head which psychologically predispose me to conceiving and honoring deontic language) and of abstract things (propositional content and attitudes and rationality about physical things)...

Comment: I think if one admits abstract objects, one cannot fully admit them as physical objects, but rather as abstractions with physical reductions. I think it is idiomatic to claim that persons can be obligations with the paraphrasing always being that it presumes that persons qua obligations is a paraphrase of persons being the object of obligations; as such there is nothing unseemly about having obligations have physical objects as linguistic complements in the various constructions possible.